# How to extract values in a certain order in multiple columns at once with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to pandas and having some trouble with extracting values in several columns at once in a certain order. The data is an export of a query on scientific papers in [Web of Science](https://webofknowledge.com). My data has many columns, but the most important ones looks like this:

| authors | email addresses | addresses | researcher_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gates, B; Bezos, J; Musk, E | gates@univ.edu | [Gates, Bill; Bezos, Jeff] univ1, dept of math, USA; [Musk, Elon] univ2, dept of physics, FR | Zuckerberg, Mark S/5322005 |
| Slim, C; Buffet, W | slim@univ3.edu; buffet12@univ4.edu | [Slim, Carlos] univ3, dept of radiology, USA; [Buffet, Warren] univ4, dept of math, DE | Slim, Carlos/3223422 |

The preferred output is:

| author | author_full_name | email_address | address | researcher_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gates, B | Gates, Bill | gates@univ1.edu | univ1, Dept of Math | None |
| Bezos, J | Bezos, Jeff | None | univ1, Dept of Math | None |
| Musk, E | Musk, Elon | None | univ2, Dept of Physics | None |
| None | None | None | None | Zuckerberg, Mark S/5322005 |
| Slim, C | Slim, Carlos | univ3, dept of radiology, USA | Slim, Carlos/3223422 |  |
| Buffet, W | Buffet, Warren | buffet12@univ4.edu | univ4, dept of math | None |

My question: is there a way to iterate through each column in each row and:

- Extract author from authors column.
- Check len of email addresses. If len is the same as all authors, extract in the same order.
- Extract addresses. The author names seem to be in a list, but it is actually a string. Authors working at the same university are within brackets. Different universities are separated by semicolon.
- If len researcher id is the same as len authors, extract in the same order.

It would also be interesting to try to match the email addresses and researcher ids of the length is not the same.

What I've done: I've cleaned and parsed the addresses to a new dataframe. I can do the same for all the other fields. Then I can merge them later on author_name or publication_name to create a new dataframe to my liking. The problem is that many author names are the same, but actually different people. Authors also change universities. That makes the merging part problematic. It's also rather cumbersome. I've got the feeling there must be a much simpler option, but I can't find the solution here on stackoverflow.

The solution would be to iterate through the columns row by row, but I can't get my head around how to keep order iterating through the different columns.

Can someone give me some pointers on this?

Thanks.

Comment: For the example data provided, what's the expected output dataframe?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I've edited the question.

Comment: Because you have a lot of conditions to test, I don't believe there's a simple solution to your problem.

Comment: Welcome. Your problem seems to be an interesting one, but to have an answer that actually answers your full problem do this: `(1)` give a minimal reproducible example with `df.to_dict()`, and that your reproducible example contains observations with the problem of `many author names are the same, but actually different people. Authors also change universities.`. `(2)` Post your code attempt and your code results and explain what's missing from your attempt. And yes, there is an easier way using `apply()`, but I don't know using it with words and lists.